# what is the command to restart firefox from the command line?

Tags: command-line, firefox, restart

how to restart firefox from the command-line. I have already given as "firefox". Is this the right command to restart the firefox?

Answer (score 8):

First kill all processes that is named Firefox which means killing the existing running firefox then run it again

```
pkill firefox
firefox &
```

Comment: @sriraj you are welcome but if you find this help you it's better to mark as answer and upvote

Answer (score 7):

At least in my version, Firefox doesn't have a restart option. You can kill the process and then start it again. For example:

```
killall firefox
firefox
```

If `killall` doesn't cut it, you can use `pkill` instead. Just keep in mind that `pkill` would kill any process with `firefox` in its name, though probably that's not a big concern.

Comment: what is the difference in`killall` and `pkill`?

Comment: Just a note: This solution does not work when you want to restart `Firefox` from a non-GUI shell (such as SSH connection).

Answer (score 7):

#### Update

In the address bar write

1. `about:profiles`
   then press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> button a couple of times to select the `Restart Normally` or the `Restart with Add-ons Disabled` button on the loaded page, and finally press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. `about:restartrequired` then press  <kbd>Enter</kbd> (it should be already selected else you can always press <kbd>Tab</kbd>).

---

Under Linux it is possible to use from command line

```
pkill -f firefox && firefox 2>/dev/null &
```

killing all the processes with word `firefox` in the whole (full) command line, redirecting the error log to `/dev/null`; maybe after checking with `pgrep -fl firefox`.

---

#### It's a command line but an internal one...

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, write `restart` in the opened bar (at the very bottom), then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

On old versions, e.g. the *41.0.2*, it was needed to write the word **true** too: `restart true`.

#### Some words more

It's possible to force firefox to restart through the [Developer Toolbar](https://superuser.com/questions/992382/how-to-force-to-restart-firefox-in-a-clean-way), usually accessible via <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> or via menu (`Firefox/Tools >> Web Developer >> Developer Toolbar` in the English version).

A bar will be opened in the bottom of the page where it will be possible to write the command

```
restart
```

It is possible to use `restart --nocache true` or `restart --nocache false` in order to force it the refresh of the tabs content or to use the local cached instead. It can result useful the `--safemode` option too.

You can find some words more and the old synopsis on [another answer](https://superuser.com/questions/992382/how-to-force-to-restart-firefox-in-a-clean-way) of mine on SuperUser.

Comment: In Firefox 93.0 the shortkey is <Alt>+F2, and the "restart" command will restart only the current Firefox instance

Comment: @j.c Updated with a couple of methods you can use instead. From  version 62 (in September 2018) there is no more Developer Toolbar, there is a Console under the Web Developer Tools (Ctrl+Shift+I), but no more restart command (at least under Linux )... It is needed to use one of the two methods above.

Answer (score 4):

The below would be better since using nohup is cleaner and forcing firefox to stop wit -9 is sometimes important

```
pkill -9 firefox
nohup firefox &
```

Comment: what is the meaning `-9` in the `pkill` command

Comment: it forces killing the process